# Should I use the Reply-To header when sending emails as a service to others?

Tags: email, spam, email-headers, phishing

Suppose we have an application that acts as a middleman, allowing Company A to send reports to their customers.

> Company A → Company B (me) → Company A's customers

After getting the report we send email notifications to the recipients, but they necessarily originate from our company notifications email address, e.g.

> joe.bloggs@a.com → notifications@b.com → peter@c.com

Now, customers tend to reply to those email notifications, wanting them to go back to whoever sent the report at Company A. Instead, they end up back at our address, notifications@b.com.

A simple solution may be to change the `Reply-To` header to the relevant Company A address on the notifications we send, e.g.

> joe.bloggs@a.com → notifications@b.com [Reply-To: joe.bloggs@a.com] → peter@c.com

But my main concerns are:

- The complete discrepancy in email address and domain between the `From` and `Reply-To` fields might make spam or phishing filters more eager to flag the emails.
- Not all email clients may respect the `Reply-To` field when people actually click "Reply", and just use `From` instead. A lesser concern, unless widespread.

Are these concerns founded at all? Or are there other concerns I should have?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You may want to consider placing the customer's name in the `From` header and your address in the `Sender` header:

```
From: Company A <joe.bloggs@a.com>
Sender: notifications@b.com
```

Most mailers will render this as "From notifications@b.com on behalf of Company A", which is accurate.  And then a `Reply-To` of Company A's address won't seem out of sorts.

From [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.2):

> The "From:" field specifies the author(s) of the message,
> that is, the mailbox(es) of the person(s) or system(s) responsible
> for the writing of the message.  The "Sender:" field specifies the
> mailbox of the agent responsible for the actual transmission of the
> message.  For example, if a secretary were to send a message for
> another person, the mailbox of the secretary would appear in the
> "Sender:" field and the mailbox of the actual author would appear in
> the "From:" field.

Comment: I don't really want my owner answer upvoted, but worth mentioning is this useful question and answer, which basically confirms dkarp's answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231897/potential-issues-using-members-from-address-and-the-sender-header

Comment: If it's for circularization it won't work @a and @b are different domains, most servers don't allow to send in behalf of someone from another domain. B will have to forward it, but you can always add a hidden multipart. Everybody knows how to forward to another address.

Comment: Any updates from 2018 on deliverability when using the From field in this way?

Answer (score 185):

I tested dkarp's solution with gmail and it was filtered to spam.  **Use the Reply-To header** instead (or in addition, although gmail apparently doesn't need it).  Here's how linkedin does it:

```
Sender: messages-noreply@bounce.linkedin.com
From: John Doe via LinkedIn <member@linkedin.com>
Reply-To: John Doe <John.Doe@gmail.com>
To: My Name <My.Name@gmail.com>
```

Once I switched to this format, gmail is no longer filtering my messages as spam.

Comment: Is member@linkedin.com just a generic catch-all address, or should it actually read john.doe@linkedin.com in your example?

Comment: @Sean No, only John Doe and My Name are edited for my example.  "Member" is unchanged.

Comment: This is the method we've used.  However, we're now having problems with a few servers (...ehmm.. AOL) bouncing messages, stating they don't comply with their policy.  The only explanation we've received is that the reply-to header and from header have different domains, even though this seems to be the exact intent of having two different headers.   It's starting to get really frustrating to rely on email for B2B communications on multi-tenant apps any more.

Comment: @BrianH: AOL and Yahoo apparently now have agressive DMARC validation. This has caused me problems with the 'From:' address to AOL. http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C4/could_yahoo_and_aols_dmarc_policies_destroy_your_deliverability.

Comment: The downside of this approach is that the recipient's address book (in many e-mail clients) now contains "John Doe via LinkedIn <member@linkedin.com>". And when an unknowing recipient wants to contact John Doe again, this address pops up when writing his name in the To field of a new message (thus: "via LinkedIn" is of significant importance from a UX side).

Comment: Updated link for the blog post @EML linked to: https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/industry-news/could_yahoo_and_aols_dmarc_policies_destroy_your_deliverability/ ... it does go into some depth on the aol/yahoo.com issues.

Comment: As a related note, it looks like sending an email with the suggested header through Gmail will create a new entry `X-Google-Original-From` and place the `From` there, then replace `From` with the `Sender`.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking into this recently, my answer is same as others, however, I believe its definitions are clearer to a layman:

1. `From` should be described as the author of the message
2. `Sender` should be described as the transmitter of the message
3. `Reply-To` should not be confused with 1 and 2, it simply means where the receipient should write to if they choose to respond

Thus in some clients (e.g. Outlook 2003), you will see

> From: `Sender` on behalf of `From`

Answer (score 0):

After reading all of this, I might just embed a hyperlink in the email body like this:

To reply to this email, click here <a href="mailto:...">Third.Party@theirdomain.com</a>

Answer (score -4):

Here is worked for me:

```
Subject: SomeSubject
From:Company B (me)
Reply-to:Company A
To:Company A's customers
```