# Sending mail with the email entered by user in the from address

Tags: email, email-address

When a user sends some enquiry through a company's website, he also enters email,

now is there a way where the email when received to the enquiry department will reflect as :

From : user@xyz.com

to : enquiry@myCompany.com

Subject: enquiry

Some Text

where "user@xyz.com" is the email entered by user in the enquiry form.

the same can be seen in some e-card website, where you send ecard to your friends email and they receive it with your address in the "from" part.

how can this be achieved?

**------------EDIT-------------**
Example:

Front-End :

To send ecard to your friend:
your email address : abc@xyz.com
your friends email address: lmn@pqr.com

and then friend receives an email as:

**from: abc@xyz.com via jkh.hk.dn.net**
to: lmn@pqr.com
subject: ecard
ecard email

as you can see though the email is send the e-card website, the from address reflect the email address entered by user.

So need some help on how this can be achieved? and any example would be more helpful...

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking as from what I understand is available in even the most basic of email scripts. What have you tried already?

Comment: @VincePettit i have made an edit to help it make understandable

Comment: So what have you actually tried? As I said there are some basic scripts that if you search online you'll find. For example a quick search on Google provides me with a link to this site - http://www.hotscripts.com/category/scripts/php/scripts-programs/postcards/

Comment: Now we're on SO (which kinda alters the focus of this question)... what server-side language are you using and what have you tried already? Any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have more success using the "reply-to" and "sender" fields, which can be different to the from address, and most mail clients should honour - and has less "spammy" connotations:

So your form has:

```
From address: user@abc.com
To address: friend@xyz.com
```

Then when you generate the email you send it as:

```
from: website@example.com // Your domain name, that is allowed to send emails
to: friend@xyz.com
reply-to: user@abc.com
```

This way the receiving mail server can see you're being honest about where the email is coming from, and if they check any SPF records for the `from` domain they should match with your server. However when the user hits "Reply" the email should go to the Reply-to address instead.

If you really want to set the user's email as the `from` field then you should set the system email address as the `sender`:

```
from: user@abc.com
sender: website@example.com
to: friend@xyz.com
reply-to: user@abc.com
```

This will result in the email appearing as "From website@example.com on behalf of user@abc.com".

See also the following Stack Overflow question:

> [Should I use the Reply-To header when sending emails as a service to others?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4728393/33051)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this, but it depends on what rights your mail server has. When I manage servers, I ensure this option is disabled. You will need to talk to whoever managers your SMTP server; However, as a web developer I know why you want it but I strongly advise against.

What you are proposing is very dangerous as you're sending email via someone's domain without their permission. This then means technically, I can come to your website and fill in any message and any email addresses and 'SPAM' via your service.

You are better to have the email set as
    From name@Mycompay
    To   customer@hisDomain
    BCC  name@MYCompany

Comment: +1, Also, Google Mail (and others email providers too I guess) will detect this and have a big warning saying "This email might not come from the above address" or something similar

Comment: Ah yes - I've seen this even with Hotmail. I had forgotten about this.

Comment: @milo5b: I use Gmail and have used the `From: user@xyz.com` technique on several sites on different servers but have never actually had the "this email might not have come from the above address" under these circumstances.