# How to add Sender email header using Mandrill Mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mandrill

Using [`mandrill mailer`](https://github.com/renz45/mandrill_mailer).  I want to add a `Sender` header to my email to have something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14555043), but I can't see to find how in the docs to add that additional header.

How do I add `Sender` to my email using `mandrill mailer`?

Answer (score 0):

The closest way to do this was the following:
If you are sending from yourdomain.com and you want to send on behalf of "email@example.com" then....

Set the "From" part of the message to be from "email@example.com" and set the "signingdomain" part of the message to be "yourdomain.com".
This will create a message with the following headers:

From: email@example.com
Sender: email@yourdomain.com.

If you add a reply-to header, you'll be able to prevent replies going to email@yourdomain.com.

I realise this was not what you asked for, however this seemed to be the only option given to you.

When I set Sender Headers and on-behalf-of Headers myself Mandrill seemed to chuck them out, only allowing reply-to. :/

Comment: Sadly that's no longer the case, from their docs:

"If you signed up for a Mandrill account on or after December 1st, 2015, you must add SPF and DKIM records and verify ownership of your sending domains before you can send email through your account. Mandrill will not send any email from unverified domains or domains without valid SPF and DKIM records, including public domains like gmail.com, yahoo.com, and more.

If you signed up for a new Mandrill account on or after December 1st, 2015, the X-MC-SigningDomain header will be ignored."