# My PHP form wont send me an email

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have a rather simple HTML/PHP form that just needs to send the data to my email. The email I'm using is not using the same domain as the website.
I've been stuck on this for hours now and I cant seem to find the solution. Could someone take a look?

```
<?php

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$email = $_POST['email"];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = $_POST['user_name']; 
$to = 'example@email.com'; 
$subject = 'Comment';


$body = "From: $first_name\n From: $last_name\n Sex: $gender\n Username: $user_name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
  if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo 'Your message has been sent!';
  } else { 
    echo 'Something went wrong, go back and try again!'; 
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Your line `$email = $_POST['email"];` has mismatched quotation marks. Use `"email"` or `'email'`, but not `'email"`.

Comment: http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/protect-script-from-email-injection.shtml

http://securephpwiki.com/index.php/Email_Injection

Comment: Is the form method set to post? **method="post"?

Comment: @CamilStaps You are correct. That dupe is used for any "why doesn;t this form work" questions that have no specific error message. But the root cause of this issue is obvious so I removed it.

Comment: @CodingHorror The issue is a typo. You don't need to see the form.

Comment: The use of an editor with syntax highlighting would have easily prevented this question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your PHP code file is **sendMail.php**

let this be **form.html**

```
<form name="sendMail" id="sendMail" action="sendMail.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" /> 
    <input type="text" name="last_name" /> 
    <input type="text" name="message" /> 
    <input type="text" name="gender" /> 
    <input type="text" name="user_name" /> 
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Basically, your PHP code should work according to the form above. Of course you may want to change gender field to radiogroup/dropdown and/or message to textarea.

```
<?php
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = $_POST['user_name']; 
$to = 'example@email.com'; 
$subject = 'Comment';


$body = "From: $first_name\n From: $last_name\n Sex: $gender\n Username: $user_name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo 'Your message has been sent!';
    }
    else { 
        echo 'Something went wrong, go back and try again!'; 
    }
}
?>
```

There is one point to correct that `$email = $_POST['email"];` should be `$email = $_POST['email'];`.

And you should ensure that PHP mail settings have to be set properly. I suggest you to use PHPMailer which is so simple and runs smoothly with too few configuration.

Answer (score 1):

### The PHP

The fourth parameter of the [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function should be a list of additional email headers. You're passing it a user name. You should have something like this:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$email = preg_replace('/[[:cntrl:]]/', '', $email);
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
...
mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

The second line filters out control characters from the email address. Without this, a malicious user could insert newline characters to add their own email headers, such as `CC:` headers to send unsolicited spam.

### Mixing domains

Also, you might not be allowed to send email with a `From:` address from a different domain name than your web site (or mail server). You could contact the administrator of your server/web site and ask what your options are.

Some things to consider:

- You could try to use a local `From:` address and leave the actual (external) email address in the `Reply-To:` header. Eg:

  ```
    $headers  = "From: Me@mydomain.example\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: Someone@otherdomain.example\r\n";
  ```

  Some email clients might not respect the `Reply-To:` header, though.
- If the address in the `From:` header is not the actual sender of the email, you **should** specify the *real* sender in a `Sender:` header. Eg:

  ```
    $headers  = "From: Someone@otherdomain.example\r\n";
    $headers .= "Sender: Me@mydomain.example\r\n";
  ```
- You *may* need to specify the `From:` address in an additional parameter to the Mail Transfer Agent:

  ```
    mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-f '$email'");
  ```
- Sending email from a different domain name *may* count against you by SPAM filters. You may need an [SPF record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) to ensure that your emails go through.
- You might be better off using a full-featured email class, such as [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) rather than the crude `mail()` function.

### See also

#### Documentation

- [RFC 5322 - Internet Message Format: 3.6.2. Originator Fields](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.2)
- [The PHP mail() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)
- [SPF - Sender Policy Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework)

#### Stack Overflow

- [Should I use the Reply-To header when sending emails as a service to others?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4728393)
- [How do you make sure email you send programmatically is not automatically marked as spam?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/371)
- [Potential issues using member's "from" address and the "sender" header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2231897)

Answer (score 1):

Just write isset() in first if condition.

try above code again.

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];

$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];

$message = $_POST['message'];

$gender = $_POST['gender'];

$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];

$email = $_POST['email"];

$message = $_POST['message'];

$from = $_POST['user_name']; 

$to = 'example@email.com'; 

$subject = 'Comment';


$body = "From: $first_name\n From: $last_name\n Sex: $gender\n Username: $user_name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo 'Your message has been sent!';
  } else { 
    echo 'Something went wrong, go back and try again!'; 
  }
}
```