# Specify the "send via"- or "on behalf of"-value in Mandrill

Tags: php, email, mandrill

I'm using Mandrill to send E-Mails in my PHP Project and integrated it via the API. So far so good E-Mails go out and arrive their recipient, but something bothers me about the missing SPF and DKIM entries.

When the E-Mails are opened in outlook the "on behalf of" issue  occurs ([FAQ from mandrills KB](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582237-How-do-I-get-rid-of-the-on-behalf-of-message-that-shows-for-some-recipients-)). But I can't fix this, since too many of our customers do not have the necessary skills/ access-rights to create a SPF entry for their domain, so we learned to live with that.

We verified our own domain at mandrill to use it as [custom sending-domain](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582387-How-do-I-set-up-sending-domains-) to get rid of the

```
from: reallyLongString@mandrillapp.com on behalf of customerName@customerDomain.com
```

and exchange it with

```
from: mailbot@ourDomain.com on behalf of customerName@customerDomain.com
```

but somehow I can't get this to work!

I cannot find an option to set "mailbot" as sender. Even worse, Mandrill makes up a phantasy e-mail-address consisting of **customerName@ourDomain.com**. If some customer gets the idea to send to this address we've got a disaster upcoming. Also the API does not specify anything like that in the "Messages"-Section.

How can I configure mandrill to send E-Mails with a from-field appearing in outlook like this:

```
mailbot@ourDomain.com on behalf of customerName@customerDomain.com
```

? Really cannot find anything in the docs or the web. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to clarify into a question about the problem you are having. "Anyone with a similar problem/solution?" is very vague. You did a decent job of describing the issue you are having, but still need to ask a question about what you would like to do about it.  Hope this helps, and welcome to SO.

Comment: Ty, was a bit in a hurry towards the end ;-)
Hopefully clarified it.

Comment: You may not be able to control the "on behalf of" right side, and definitely can not control the left side as that is the email address the server is actually authenticating and sending from.  If concerned about customers replying to a funky address, you could set the "replyto" address to something static :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sanuel Jackson already indicated, there is no way to do this WITHOUT doing the whole certification process of creating a SPF entry.

Also confirmed by Mandrill support (which was quite fast AND competent in responding)

I'm now sending with a proper reply-to address and hope, that our customer's customers ignore the funky e-mail adresses... In case they do mind them, our customers are free to engage us regarding a SPF-entry ;-)

Comment: Beware that many email clients simply ignore the reply-to header...

See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231897/potential-issues-using-members-from-address-and-the-sender-header