# Email "reply-to" is being ignored in favour of "from"

Tags: email, sendgrid, spf, dkim

We have an app that sends emails on behalf of our clients. All emails are sent via Sendgrid. As part of this we have verified our email sending domains via DKIM and SPF.

When our clients send email, it is constructed as follows:

```
from: Tom Smith <email-service@ourserver.com>  
reply-to: tom.smith@email.com
```

This works in the vast majority of cases, but there are situations where the "reply-to" is not being respected - recipients are clicking "Reply" in their email clients and the reply is coming back to us.

Is there something that we are missing here. Do we need to explicitly set a FROM or SENDER header? Or something else?

Comment: Is it possible for you to post the email message headers, with private info redacted?

Comment: Could it be that it's broken for gmail users? Gmail's reply-to handling is horribly broken, not much you can do about it.

Comment: What specific email clients/systems do you know are behaving this way? IT very well could be the client or system doesn't "correctly" respect/behave the reply-to header.

Comment: How do I get the email message headers if its going through Sendgrid's SMTP servers?

Comment: You'll need to get the raw MIME message from an email client. For example in gmail you can click "Show Original"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Potential issues using member's "from" address and the "sender" header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231897/potential-issues-using-members-from-address-and-the-sender-header)